# How to run Sonar 4.1 on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, sonarqube

How can I run Sonar on my Unix system with Tomcat. In previous versions there was way to make .war and deploy it on Tomcat.

I tried to put into folder webaps (Tomcat) and run script **sonarqube-4.1\bin\solaris-x86-32\sonar.sh**. Everything was OK, but I didn't know what to write in webbrowser to get to Sonar.

**Version of my OS**: *SunOS mdjava0.mydevil.net 5.11 joyent_20131213T023304Z i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is no longer supported as of 4.0.

> ### End of Support of WAR deployment Mode
>
> The standalone mode is now the only mode that is supported. Standalone mode embeds a Tomcat server.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.0+Upgrade+Notes

Comment: On which port start this sonar-tomcat?

Comment: OK I found it. Just edit lines: # TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
sonar.web.port=9999

Comment: Is it maybe still possible to build the war file for Version 4.4.5 on my own?

Comment: Running embedded tomcat is a waste of resources